# Can iterate through an array with forEach, but not with List

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an array of notes (viewModel.list) that I would like to display in a List. All notes conform to Identifiable.

When I use ForEach, all notes appear just fine:

```
   ForEach(viewModel.list){ note in
         NoteView(namespace:namespace, note: note)
   }
```

But if I change this to a List no objects appear:

```
List(viewModel.list){ note in
    NoteView(namespace:namespace, note: note)
}
```

The same thing happens if I embed the ForEach in a List

```
  List{
      ForEach(viewModel.list){ note in
          NoteView(namespace:namespace, note: note)
      }
  }
```

I want to use a List because I would like to add a swipeAction to every NoteView which can only be used in Lists. Is there any reason this behavior is happening?

UPDATE: I have uploaded a reproducible example below and believe it has something to do with embedding the List in a ScrollView. If I remove the ScrollView, this code works fine, but nothing shows up with it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Note: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var content: String = ""
}
var notes = [
    Note(content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectet adipiscing elit. Condimentum quisque id vitae convallis dignissim pharetra nisl est creatus"),
    Note(content: "Mauris ac tempor libero, non eleifend lectus. Mauris eu hendrerit nunc. Donec at ante mauris. Duis ac elit purus. Mauris ullamcorper mi."),
    Note(content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectet adipiscing elit. Condimentum quisque id vitae convallis dignissim pharetra nisl est creatus"),
    Note(content: "Mauris ac tempor libero, non eleifend lectus. Mauris eu hendrerit nunc. Donec at ante mauris. Duis ac elit purus. Mauris ullamcorper mi.")
]


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            List(notes){ note in
                NoteView(note: note)
                    .padding(.bottom)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NoteView: View {
    var note: Note = notes[0]
  
    var body: some View {
        Text(note.content)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are there any error messages in the xcode console?

Comment: No it builds perfectly fine. Just no notes appear in the List.

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example

Comment: Just added it. I believe it has something to do with having a list in a scrollview

Answer (score 2):

List is not showing because `List` infer it size from its parent View. So when you embed it inside something like `Scrollview` that have dynamic height, it can't infer it size correctly.

Also **List** behaves like a **UIScrollView** (an arbitrarily long scrollable view of views).

So no need to wrap `List` inside scrollview.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
       // ScrollView {
            List(notes){ note in
                NoteView(note: note)
                    .padding(.bottom)
            }
        // }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `List` from `ScrollView` - it is scrollable itself.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(notes){ note in
            NoteView(note: note)
                .padding(.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

*the reason of the issue is that List wants to take parent size to expand, but ScrollView does not have own size and expects from content a size that needs to be scrolled, result is obvious - cycling conflict - to do not crash/hang in cycling SwiftUI breaks layout - output is empty.